# System Call Analysis

Tags: windows, system-calls, malware, n-gram

I've heard of n-gram analysis which seems to be a relatively popular way to analyze and find patterns in system calls in Windows or any other operating systems. Does anyone have suggestions on other ways to analyze system calls to determine certain patterns, frequencies of specific calls, etc?

This is part of my research on malware and the detection of malware. The end goal is to be able to detect when a malware is running.

Comment: So you can write your own malware or malware detection program? Read [ask], this is way too broad to answer.

Comment: Yes, a malware detection program. I just edited my question in response to what you just said.